# Microsoft Flow/other extracting information from SharePoint survey list

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, sharepoint-survey-list

I have a SharePoint survey. The problem I am having is that once people complete the survey, SharePoint simply stores the responses and only gives me the option to download them onto a spreadsheet or view them on the site.

I am looking for a way, either using Microsoft Flow or other workflow mechanism, to have the system recognize that person A from a SharePoint list responded to the survey, therefore their task is complete. This way, if someone on that list has not responded, they would get a reminder email to do so.

I have created a Microsoft Flow program that searches a list of names every day and another list of dates, so it then knows when to send the original emails with the link to the survey and to whom.

However, I need another Microsoft Flow program or something to somehow check the survey responses, the created by and date of completion of the survey and determine who still needs to complete the survey. The survey list does keep track of whether the survey is completed,  but I cannot figure out a way for Flow to see this survey list as any other sharepoint list.

Maybe SharePoint would allow survey responses to flow into a sharepoint list that Flow can see and I can go from there?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of a SharePoint list for your survey, create the survey in Forms and then create a Flow for any new Form responses for that survey.